# httphandler not working correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net, httphandler

I'm trying to redirect a user only if the user is logged in to a different page. I'm using `HTTPHandler` to intercept this request and redirect. After the user is logged in the control does not return to this `HTTPHandler`. Any ideas or suggestions

```
namespace NES.HiLo.Security
{
    public class PallativeAuthenticationHandler : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// You will need to configure this handler in the web.config file of your 
        /// web and register it with IIS before being able to use it. For more information
        /// see the following link: http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=8101007
        /// </summary>


        public bool IsReusable
        {
        // Return false in case your Managed Handler cannot be reused for another request.
        // Usually this would be false in case you have some state information preserved per request.
        get { return false; }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {

        string UserName = "";
        int TSecUserID = 0;

        HttpContext context2 = HttpContext.Current;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(context2.User.Identity.Name))
            UserName = "UNKNOWN";
        else
            UserName = context2.User.Identity.Name.ToString();

        if (UserName != "UNKNOWN")
        {

            string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NES.HiLo.Data.Properties.Settings.HiLoConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {

                connection.Open();
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select tSec_UserId from dbo.HiLoUser where Username='" + HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString() + "'", connection);


                TSecUserID = (Int32)command.ExecuteScalar();
                connection.Close();
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com?retUrl=" + TSecUserID);

            }

        }
        else
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx?retUrl=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(context2.Request.Url.ToString()));

        }



    }
}
```

Httphanlder entries in web.config

```
<httpHandlers>
        <!--<add path="*.pdf" type="HttpSecurity.HttpHandlerAuthentication, HttpSecurity"  verb="*"/>-->

        <!--<add verb="GET" path="/calderdale/*/*.pdf" type="NES.HiLo.Security.CalderDaleAuthenticationHandler, NES.HiLo.Security" />-->
        <add verb="*" path="/calderdale/*.pdf" type="NES.HiLo.Security.CalderDaleAuthenticationHandler, NES.HiLo.Security" />
        <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx" />
        <!-- ASPNETAJAX -->
        <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false" />
        <!-- UMBRACO CHANNELS -->
        <add verb="*" path="umbraco/channels.aspx" type="umbraco.presentation.channels.api, umbraco" />
        <add verb="*" path="umbraco/channels/word.aspx" type="umbraco.presentation.channels.wordApi, umbraco" />
        <add verb="*" path="umbraco/clt/ajaxCommunityAdministrators.aspx" type="NES.HiLo.UserControls.DataTypes.AjaxCommunityAdministrators, NES.HiLo" />
        <!-- ELMAH -->
        <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
        <!-- WIDGET AJAX HANDLER -->
        <add verb="*" path="umbraco/WidgetLibrary/WidgetAjaxHandler.aspx" type="NES.WidgetLibrary.WidgetAjaxHandler" />
        <add verb="GET" path="umbraco/WidgetLibrary/SubjectSelectorAjaxHandler.aspx" type="NES.WidgetLibrary.MetaDataControls.ChildControls.SubjectSelectorControl.AjaxSelector" />
        <add verb="*" path="/FilterByDevice.ashx" type="NES.HiLo.Web.Handlers.DeviceFilterHandler" />
        <add verb="GET" path="/Pallative/*.xml" type="NES.HiLo.Security.PallativeAuthenticationHandler, NES.HiLo.Security" />
    </httpHandlers>




 <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms name="KFCSAUTH" loginUrl="login.aspx" protection="All" slidingExpiration="true" path="/" domain=".scot.nhs.uk" />
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
        <allow users="?" />
    </authorization>

 <system.webServer>
    <!--<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />-->
    <handlers>
        <add name="Pallative Handler" path="/Pallative/*.xml" verb="GET" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv2.0,bitness32" />
        <add name="Calderdale Handler" path="/calderdale/*.pdf" verb="GET" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv2.0,bitness32" />
        <!--<add name="Pallative Handler" path="Pallative/pallative_doc.html" verb="GET" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv2.0,bitness32" />-->
    </handlers>
    <!--<handlers  accessPolicy="Read, Write, Script, Execute">
      -->
    <!--<add name="PictHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="*.pictx" type="PictHttpHandler,PictHandler"/>-->
    <!--
      <add name="Pdfhandler" verb="*" path="/calderdale/*.html" type="NES.HiLo.Security.CalderDaleAuthenticationHandler, NES.HiLo.Security" preCondition="integratedMode" />
  </handlers>-->

</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Could you post the `web.config` section which configures this handler?

Comment: web.config for this app is quite big. I can copy a section of it if that is any good. I have posted some relevant sections above and by the way i m using IIS 7.5

Comment: So, what is the class name for this handler?

Comment: The classname is PallativeAuthenticationHandler.cs and I have added the complete code above. thanks

Comment: Are you sure that the user is authenticated? You use `<allow users="?" />`, which basically says that anonymous users are allowed. What is the URL you are hitting in order to trigger this handler?

Comment: the url i m hitting is http://local.knowledge.scot.nhs.uk/Pallative/1.xml

Comment: the handler is triggered but for some reasons HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name is always emtpy even when the user is logged in.

Comment: If you access the URL directly, is the handler intercepting your request (can you reach any breakpoint in the `ProcessRequest` method)?

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing has something to do with the fact that the authentication cookie is valid only for the domain specified:

```
<forms name="KFCSAUTH" 
    loginUrl="login.aspx" 
    protection="All" 
    slidingExpiration="true" 
    path="/" 
    domain=".scot.nhs.uk" />
```

Maybe this problem occurs only when you are running the web application in some other domain. Try removing the `domain` attribute and see if the issue persists.

Comment: I have created another httphandler which works as expected to intercept any requests for the pdf file. Using similar web.config entries